# Change select width to fit div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have defined a dropdwon as fellow:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>small option</option>
            <option>mediummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm option</option>                
            <option>large eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeee option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I want to change `select` width to be minimum of container width and `option` text width. If `option` text is bigger than `div` container, truncate  option's text and put ellipsis at the end. So the `option` stays inside the container. Also `select` must be responsive, When resizing window, `select` width should be updated to fit new window width.

How can I achieve that using bootstrap CSS?

Comment: please check the accepeted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672586/how-to-make-select-elements-shrink-to-max-width-percent-style-within-fieldset

Answer (score 7):

try `width:100%;`

It works for me each element in ListView

Answer (score -1):

I took this answer from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938325/how-to-truncate-text-in-select-box-using-css-only)

```css
.dropdown{
 width:150px;
 border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding:3px 4px 4px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.dropdown select{
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0;
 width:150px;
    /* background: url(http://i57.tinypic.com/nnmgpy_th.png) no-repeat right; */
    /* background-position: 55%; */
 }

/* not 100% sure this next option rule is needed */
.dropdown option {
    width:150px
}

/* this places an arbitrary element inside the dropdown but before it's children elements */
/* We use it to cover half the select box as well as display the custom arrow */
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <select>
       <option value="">Some Text</option>
        <option value="">Some More Text2</option>
        <option value="">Some More More More Longer Text</option>
    </select>
                                
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of hardcoding the width to 150px. Also this is not responsive. If you change container width, `select` width  remains the same.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should look into plugins that can style the select box as you would want  : http://selectric.js.org/demo.html